# How to refresh the tableview after deleted

Tags: javascript, cross-platform, titanium-mobile

i am able to delete tableviewrow when click on button,bt one problem is that it delete from row from database but not reflected in view.js file.to see effect of query i need to start application again.i want to display the row when click on button immediately instead if start application again.could u suggest me how could i achieve that.
here is my code

```
if (e.index === e.source.del)             
    {

    var db=Titanium.Database.install('/mydata/ToDoDB', 'ToDoDB');
    var d=db.execute("DELETE FROM task WHERE content =?",delrow);
    yourTable.deleteRow(e.source.i);
                    // rowview.setData(yourTable.data);
    Ti.API.info('The Delete  button was clicked'+e.index);

    }
```

it shows deleted rows after running applicaton.

Comment: function loadWindowData() {
 Ti.API.info('refreshdata');
 setArray(); // call your tableview function again
   }
Ti.App.addEventListener('refreshTable',loadWindowData);  Titanium.App.fireEvent('refreshTable'); try this.

Comment: Are you sure `e.source.i` has the correct index of the row you are deleting? Your code is a bit incomplete.

Comment: yes.it deleted selected rows.bt shows after running app